# No se me muestra los datos del puntero al consultar

Tags: sql, sql-server

A base de la siguiente pregunta:

1. Elaborar un script de T-SQL que programe un cursor que tenga como listado: código empleado, nombre_empleado, dirección, total facturado (por el empleado), comision. Para aquellos empleados cuyo sueldo fluctué entre S/. 2000.00 y S/. 3500.00 y las facturas correspondan al mes de junio 2022 y que pertenezcan a las tiendas de zona Norte-01 y Norte-02. De esta consulta del cursor debe insertar en la tabla t_resumen_comision que tiene la siguiente estructura:

- Código_nombre: formato 3 primeras letras del código y 5 primeras letras del nombre.
- Total
- Comisión: se almacena el % de la comisión del vendedor.
- Sueldo
- Sueldo con comisión: incluye el sueldo y la comisión total.

Query_1:

```
CREATE DATABASE LAB_7;
GO

USE LAB_7;

-- Creación de la tabla ARTICULOS
CREATE TABLE ARTICULOS (
Clave_A INT PRIMARY KEY,
Clave_P INT,
Descripcion VARCHAR(100),
Existencia INT,
Precio_V DECIMAL(10, 2),
Punto_R INT
);
GO

-- Creación de la tabla TIENDA
CREATE TABLE TIENDA (
Clave_T INT PRIMARY KEY,
Zona VARCHAR(50),
Ciudad VARCHAR(50),
Gerente VARCHAR(50),
Gerente_V VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

-- Creación de la tabla EMPLEADOS
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS (
Clave_E INT PRIMARY KEY,
Fecha_C DATE,
Nombre VARCHAR(50),
Direccion VARCHAR(100),
Sueldo DECIMAL(10, 2),
Comision DECIMAL(10, 2),
Area VARCHAR(50),
Clave_T INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Clave_T) REFERENCES TIENDA(Clave_T)
);
GO

-- Creación de la tabla FACTURA
CREATE TABLE FACTURA (
Clave_F INT PRIMARY KEY,
Fecha DATE,
Clave_E INT,
Sub_T DECIMAL(10, 2),
Total DECIMAL(10, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (Clave_E) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(Clave_E)
);
GO

-- Creación de la tabla D_FACTURA
CREATE TABLE D_FACTURA (
Clave_F INT PRIMARY KEY,
Clave_A INT,
Cantidad INT,
Importe DECIMAL(10, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (Clave_F) REFERENCES FACTURA(Clave_F),
FOREIGN KEY (Clave_A) REFERENCES ARTICULOS(Clave_A)
);
GO

-- 1. ARTICULOS:
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS (Clave_A, Clave_P, Descripcion, Existencia, Precio_V, Punto_R)
VALUES (1, 100, 'Camisa', 50, 29.99, 10);

INSERT INTO ARTICULOS (Clave_A, Clave_P, Descripcion, Existencia, Precio_V, Punto_R)
VALUES (2, 101, 'Pantalón', 30, 49.99, 5);

-- 2. TIENDA:
INSERT INTO TIENDA (Clave_T, Zona, Ciudad, Gerente, Gerente_V)
VALUES (10, 'Norte-1', 'Ciudad A', 'Pedro Ramirez', 'Ana Sanchez');

INSERT INTO TIENDA (Clave_T, Zona, Ciudad, Gerente, Gerente_V)
VALUES (11, 'Norte-2', 'Ciudad B', 'Luis González', 'Laura Jiménez');

INSERT INTO TIENDA (Clave_T, Zona, Ciudad, Gerente, Gerente_V)
VALUES (12, 'Norte-01', 'Ciudad C', 'Roberto Hernandez', 'María Rodriguez');

INSERT INTO TIENDA (Clave_T, Zona, Ciudad, Gerente, Gerente_V)
VALUES (13, 'Norte-02', 'Ciudad D', 'Ricardo Sanchez', 'Laura Martínez');

-- 3. EMPLEADOS:
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (Clave_E, Fecha_C, Nombre, Direccion, Sueldo, Comision, Area, Clave_T)
VALUES (1001, '2023-06-15', 'Juan Perez', 'Calle 123, Ciudad A', 2500.00, 0.05, 'Ventas', 10);

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (Clave_E, Fecha_C, Nombre, Direccion, Sueldo, Comision, Area, Clave_T)
VALUES (1002, '2023-06-10', 'Ana Martinez', 'Av. Principal, Ciudad A', 2800.00, 0.04, 'Ventas', 10);

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (Clave_E, Fecha_C, Nombre, Direccion, Sueldo, Comision, Area, Clave_T)
VALUES (1003, '2023-06-12', 'Carlos López', 'Calle Central, Ciudad B', 2900.00, 0.06, 'Ventas', 11);

-- 4. FACTURA:
INSERT INTO FACTURA (Clave_F, Fecha, Clave_E, Sub_T, Total)
VALUES (5001, '2023-06-18', 1001, 100.00, 112.00);

INSERT INTO FACTURA (Clave_F, Fecha, Clave_E, Sub_T, Total)
VALUES (5002, '2023-06-19', 1002, 80.00, 90.40);

-- 5. D_FACTURA:
INSERT INTO D_FACTURA (Clave_F, Clave_A, Cantidad, Importe)
VALUES (5001, 1, 3, 89.97);

INSERT INTO D_FACTURA (Clave_F, Clave_A, Cantidad, Importe)
VALUES (5002, 2, 2, 99.98);
```

Query_2:

```
CREATE TABLE t_resumen_comision (
    Codigo_nombre VARCHAR(8),
    Total DECIMAL(10, 2),
    Comision DECIMAL(10, 2),
    Sueldo DECIMAL(10, 2),
    [Sueldo con comision] DECIMAL(10, 2)
);


DECLARE @Codigo_nombre VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @Total DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Comision DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Sueldo DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Sueldo_con_comision DECIMAL(10, 2);

DECLARE empleado_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(E.Clave_E, 3), LEFT(E.Nombre, 5)) AS Codigo_nombre,
    SUM(DF.Importe) AS Total,
    E.Comision AS Comision,
    E.Sueldo AS Sueldo,
    E.Sueldo + (SUM(DF.Importe) * E.Comision) AS Sueldo_con_comision
FROM
    EMPLEADOS E
    INNER JOIN FACTURA F ON E.Clave_E = F.Clave_E
    INNER JOIN D_FACTURA DF ON F.Clave_F = DF.Clave_F
    INNER JOIN TIENDA T ON E.Clave_T = T.Clave_T
WHERE
    E.Sueldo BETWEEN 2000.00 AND 3500.00
    AND MONTH(F.Fecha) = 6
    AND YEAR(F.Fecha) = 2023
    AND T.Zona IN ('Norte-01', 'Norte-02')
GROUP BY
    E.Clave_E, E.Nombre, E.Comision, E.Sueldo;

OPEN empleado_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM empleado_cursor INTO @Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_resumen_comision (Codigo_nombre, Total, Comision, Sueldo, [Sueldo con comision])
    VALUES (@Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision);

    FETCH NEXT FROM empleado_cursor INTO @Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision;
END;

CLOSE empleado_cursor;
DEALLOCATE empleado_cursor;
```

-- Según mi problema es que al momento de ejecutar el script se ejecuta normal, pero al momento de consultar la tabla t_resumen_comision; salen las columnas pero sin los datos que si cumplen con las condiciones del puntero. Cual es el posible error para que los datos no aparezcan en esa tabla?

Answer (score 1):

No salen datos, porque no se cumplen las condiciones del cursor.

Lo primero, el script 01, tiene incongruencias de orden. No se pueden crear, ni insertar las tablas en el orden que propones, porque se hace referencia a tablas o datos que no existen.

El orden adecuado es:

- 01 Articulos
- 02 Tienda
- 03 Empleados
- 04 Factura
- 05 D_Factura

La query que alimenta al cursor dice:

```
SELECT
    E.Clave_E,
    E.Nombre,
    E.Direccion,
    SUM(DF.Importe) AS TotalFacturado,
    E.Comision,
    E.Sueldo
FROM
    EMPLEADOS E
    INNER JOIN FACTURA F ON E.Clave_E = F.Clave_E
    INNER JOIN D_FACTURA DF ON F.Clave_F = DF.Clave_F
    INNER JOIN TIENDA T ON E.Clave_T = T.Clave_T
WHERE
    E.Sueldo BETWEEN 2000.00 AND 3500.00
    AND MONTH(F.Fecha) = 6 -- Corregir el filtro por el mes de mayo
    AND T.Zona IN ('Norte-01', 'Norte-02')
GROUP BY
    E.Clave_E,
    E.Nombre,
    E.Direccion,
    E.Comision,
    E.Sueldo;
```

[image: Res1]

Por tanto no se cumplen las condiciones, y no puede salir nada de ahí.

Comentando, la última condición. `--AND T.Zona IN ('Norte-01', 'Norte-02')`

```
DECLARE @Codigo_nombre VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @Total DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Comision DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Sueldo DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE @Sueldo_con_comision DECIMAL(10, 2);

DECLARE empleado_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(E.Clave_E, 3), LEFT(E.Nombre, 5)) AS Codigo_nombre,
    SUM(DF.Importe) AS Total,
    E.Comision AS Comision,
    E.Sueldo AS Sueldo,
    E.Sueldo + (SUM(DF.Importe) * E.Comision) AS Sueldo_con_comision
FROM
    EMPLEADOS E
    INNER JOIN FACTURA F ON E.Clave_E = F.Clave_E
    INNER JOIN D_FACTURA DF ON F.Clave_F = DF.Clave_F
    INNER JOIN TIENDA T ON E.Clave_T = T.Clave_T
WHERE
    E.Sueldo BETWEEN 2000.00 AND 3500.00
    -- aquí está el problema.....En el filtro, No hay datos para el filtro indicado
    AND MONTH(F.Fecha) = 6
    AND YEAR(F.Fecha) = 2023
    --- voy a quitar solo está parte del filtro
    --AND T.Zona IN ('Norte-01', 'Norte-02')
    
GROUP BY
    E.Clave_E, E.Nombre, E.Comision, E.Sueldo;

OPEN empleado_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM empleado_cursor INTO @Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_resumen_comision (Codigo_nombre, Total, Comision, Sueldo, [Sueldo con comision])
    VALUES (@Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision);

    FETCH NEXT FROM empleado_cursor INTO @Codigo_nombre, @Total, @Comision, @Sueldo, @Sueldo_con_comision;
END;

CLOSE empleado_cursor;
DEALLOCATE empleado_cursor;
```

[image: Res3]

Y el cursor devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto el cursor si hace algo. No se si es lo esperado, pero el problema está en el filtro de los datos.

Comment: Buenas hice lo que mencionaste acerca del orden de las tablas, aun así no se me mostraba los datos al ejecutar el cursor, hasta intente hacer de otra forma sin obtener ningún resultado. La BD esta actualizado al igual que el cursor de este problema

Comment: Te he mejorado la respuesta. El problema sigue siendo el mismo. La select que abastece el cursor, es incorrecta. Mejor dicho, no es incorrecta, no devuelve ninguna fila. Por tanto no se inserta en `t_resumen_comision`. Probablemente sea porque en la inserción en `tienda`, hay un **zonaNorte-01** y un **zonaNorte-1** y lo mismo para 2.